# Empty response for click view in google ads api

Tags: google-ads-api

I am using google Ads API to fetch the gclid associated with campaign name and campaign id.
For this I have used the following query : SELECT click_view.gclid FROM click_view WHERE segments.date DURING YESTERDAY.

In the API response I am getting an empty array.This is only for the click_view data. If I only get the campaign name from campaign table, the data is returned.

Can anyone please help me in getting the gclid?